# Have spherical dish antennae been used with Molniya satellites to avoid switch-over signal loss?

Tags: communication-satellite, antenna, molniya, parabolic

Molniya-orbit communication satellites work well for ground locations near the poles. These high eccentricity, highly inclined orbits, with a period of 12 hours,  “loiter” for about 6 hours over the poles.

A trio of 3 satellites can provide continuous coverage.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molniya_orbit

Unlike geostationary satellites (GSO) which remain over a fixed geographic location, Molniya satellites have a moving ground track. This has two consequences:

1. For Molniya reception, a tracking antenna is needed. By comparison,  GSO satellites can be received with a fixed dish
2. A Molniya antenna needs to break communication and re-acquire the next satellite 6 times a day.

**Parabolic dishes** have a primary axis which is aligned in the direction of the signal source. Parabolic dishes need to be aimed at (and track) the satellite of interest.

**Spherical dishes** have no inherent axis. The axis is determined by the location of the receiver antenna. In the sketch below, A and B are the location of focal points for objects 1 and 2 respectively.

[image]

An example is the Arecibo telescope. This dish could not be pointed, so a spherical design was used for the reflector dish, with mobile receiving antennae (illustrated below)

Two antennae (pointing at different locations in the sky) are illustrated: the spike and the sphere.

[image]
National Geographic

A fixed spherical receiving dish for a trio of Molniya satellites, with a trio of mobile antennae, could potentially provide continuous reception without re-acquisition delay. Is this a reasonable design? Ever been done?

Comment: Wouldn't it be 4 reacquisitions per day? If the loiter time is six hours, why the extra two switchovers?

Comment: Molniya satellites are always described in trios. The higher they are, the slower their angular speed. Maybe that makes tracking and re-acquisition easier ??? 3 satellites each making 2 passes a day makes for 6 reacquisitions.